# IntelliJ IDEA: authentication required, need to use ssh key

Tags: svn, authentication, intellij-idea, svnkit

I have an extremely strange issue. I reinstalled my operating system (Kubuntu 14.04), set working environment as it was (at least it seems that I made everything as usual), but when I try to make any request to subversion server, it fails - there is a popup which demands to enter the username and the password. But I can't do that, because I don't know the password. I know login and have private key and that's enough for console client.

First of all, I configured my console subversion client. I can commit or checkout anything without any passwords.
Then, I can 'browse repository' in IDEA, because there it is possible to specify private key.

What I tried:

1) Cleared auth cache in  IDEA (several times)

2) Tried to configure connection in IDEA: settings->version control->network->edit network options.

Nothing helped.

**Idea version 13.1.3.**

Please, help me, I don't know what to do.

**EDIT 1:**
I added these lines to ~/.subversion/config:

```
svnkit.ssh2.key = /home/kirill/.ssh/id_rsa
svnkit.ssh2.username = svn  
svnkit.ssh2.port = 22
```

and restarted computer. It gave no effect :(

[image: Popup which appears each time I try to do something]
[image: Settings]
[image: Can browse repository with these settings]

Comment: I am also struggling with this problem. I found that running ssh-add makes the authentication popup go away. I did not have to do this on my previous system, however. Also interesting that our circumstances are very similar. I too copied data over from a previous installation (kubuntu 12.04) to an upgraded system (kubuntu 14.04). Maybe this has something to do with 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at least I figured out what to do. I need to launch IDEA from console, not by shortcut. If I do so, there are no problems at all. Still don't understand why it is so, but I finally fixed (sort of) my problem.

**UPDATE!!! I found the exact reason!**

I had "export SVN_SSH='ssh -q -l svn'" in ~/.bashrc. But I didn't know that this is suitable just for console, so when I launch app from folder it has no effect. I put this variable in /etc/environment, rebooted and everything has worked!

Comment: Possibly there's something in your .bashrc that's missing from your .bash_profile that alleviates the problem?

Comment: Well yes, that's true, I recently figured that out. I had "export SVN_SSH='ssh -q -l svn'" in ~/.bashrc. But I didn't know that this is suitable just for console, so when I launch app from folder it has no effect. I put this variable in /etc/environment and everything has worked!